# Logistic regression: one-vs-all method for multi classification

Tags: machine-learning, classification, logistic-regression

I'm new to Machine learning. When I learn about the Logistic regression, using one-vs-all (one-vs-rest) method for multiclassification:
In logistic regression, the hypothesis function try to estimate the probability of the positive class.
Assume we have 3 classes, then each class, we should predict the hypothesis function h(x)

```
h1(x)=P(y=1|x)
h2(x)=P(y=2|x)
h3(x)=P(y=3|x)
```

However,the sum of the three probabilities doesn't equal to 1?
I "feel" that it equal to 1, and I don't understand why it doesn't.
Can someone explain why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your results are correct and the sum of `h1(x)`, `h2(x)` and `h3(x)` shouldn't be equal to 1.

As you perform one-vs-all classification, then for each class (e.g., class 1) you have two probabilities `p(y=1|x)` and `p(y!=1|x)` which sum up to 1:

```
p(y=1|x) + p(y!=1|x) = 1.
```

But, as you one-vs-all classifications are independent, then

```
p(y!=1|x) != p(y=2|x) + p(y=3|x) (at least not necessarily).
```

Maybe, it is easier to understand with an example:

- the first classifier says that p(y=1|x) = 0.7 and p(y!=1|x) = 0.3;
- the second classifier says that p(y=2|x) = 0.7 and p(y!=2|x) = 0.3;
- the third classifier says that p(y=3|x) = 0.7 and p(y!=3|x) = 0.3.

All of them are valid classifiers, but

```
p(y=1|x) + p(y=2|x) + p(y=3|x) != 1.
```

Comment: Thank you! But I'm a little confused, why the classifier are independent? I think just because the output of logistic regression is only the estimated probability, not a probability density function, so they don't sum up to 1. isn't it?